# Updating hashed passwords in Mongoose

Tags: hash, mongoose, passwords

[this mongodb blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/32866457221/password-authentication-with-mongoose-part-1) shows how to store hashed passwords. It uses a pre-hook so when a password is saved, it's automatically hashed.

However, it also states that the hook doesn't get called on an 'update' operation, just on 'save'.

How would one update a password in Mongoose via the save pre-hook method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, there should also be a `pre update` hook available. It is at the bottom of this [page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

This is the code (according to the docs) to update the **updatedAt** field.

```
schema.pre('update', function() {
    this.update({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
});
```